# Rails 3 - how to se an URL, where the form will be send

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, url, methods

I would like to ask, if is some rule for action, where is the form send... If I have a in controller

```
  def edit
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
  end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for(@shop, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
```

So in HTML source is:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/shops/11" class="edit_shop" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_shop_11" method="post">
```

And this mean, this form will be send on **:controller => 'shops'**, **:action => 'update'**.

And I am trying to change this action, where will be form send. I tried something like this:

```
<%= form_for(@shop, :url => {:controller => 'shops', :id => params[:id], :action => 'aupdate'}, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
```

But in HTML source is

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/shops/aupdate?id=11" class="edit_shop" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_shop_11" method="post">
```

I would like to ask - how is possible, the form is not send on the action **update** in this case? And what would be needed to do for it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your view:

```
<%= form_for :shop, :url => {:controller => 'shops', :action => 'aupdate', :id=> params[:id]}, :html=> {:id => "some-form-id", :multipart => true} do |f| %>

 .......

<% end %>
```

in your routes:

```
resources :shops do
   collection do
    ....
     post :aupdate
    ....
   end
end
```

in your controller:

```
def aupdate
   ....
   puts "ssssssssssssssssssssssssssss",params.inspect
   ....
end
```

Comment: Why you are using put ? your form is sending 'post' request. Use post in routes.rb file. 
resources :shops do
    put :aupdate, :on => :member
end